# Convert []byte to [32]byte in memory without copying data

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I'm looking to covert `[]byte` to `[32]byte` in Go. What's the best way? I want to reference same array in-memory, so I am not copying the data

This is the best I came up with but it's copying data...

```
var array []byte
var array32 [32]byte
copy(array32[:], array)
```

Comment: I can't do it without copying?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking to convert `[]byte` to `[32]byte` in Go. I want to reference
>   the same [underlying] array in memory, so I am not copying the data.

---

You are looking to do something that is very unsafe. To reference the byte slice underlying array, use a byte array pointer. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func byte32(s []byte) (a *[32]byte) {
    if len(a) <= len(s) {
        a = (*[len(a)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&s[0]))
    }
    return a
}

func main() {
    var (
        s []byte    // slice
        a *[32]byte // pointer to array
    )

    s = make([]byte, 32)
    a = byte32(s)
    s[0], a[1] = 42, 39
    fmt.Println(s[0], s[1], s)
    fmt.Println(a[0], a[1], *a)
}
```

Output:

```
42 39 [42 39 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
42 39 [42 39 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Comment: why is this method unsafe?

Comment: @terencetsao Because it uses the [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/) package which comes with "no guarantee". Read the package doc for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The language spec does not allow you to access "directly" the underlying, backing array of a slice. You can do that as you can see in peterSO's answer using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/), but as its name hints: it's *unsafe*.

But if you are allowed to use / pass your own slices, you can have access to its backing array if you create the slice by slicing an array. This requires no magic, the [slicing expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) do exactly this if applied on arrays: the resulting slice will use the slicing operand (the array) as its backing array.

For example:

```
var a [32]byte
s := a[:]

a[0] = 1
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(s)

s[1] = 2
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2-edPKbBUHO)):

```
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

`a` is an array and `s` is a slice. Modifying elements via any of them, "both" will change at the same time. `s` has `a` as its backing array, `s` references `a`.